# Hide download button in FlatList if file exists in Expo FileSystem

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a flatList which is looping round PDF documents from an API. The user can download documents to the Expo FileSystem. How can i hide the download button if the file exists in the Expo fileSystem?

**EDIT:**

function:

```
async checkFileExists(doc) { 
try{
  let result = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory+'app_docs/'+doc);
  console.log(result)

  if(result.exists){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
} catch(err){
  console.log(err)
}
}
```

FlatList Code:

```
      <FlatList 
        contentContainerStyle={styles.gridContainer}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.doc_id}
        data={this.state.docs}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          if(this.state.rows > 0){ 
          return(
          <View style={styles.itemBox}>
            <View style={styles.innerBox}>
              <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>{item.doc_title}</Text>
              <Text style={styles.itemDesc}>{item.doc_desc}</Text>
              {item.dl_permitted !=0 &&
                <TouchableOpacity title={item.doc_title} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('DocPdf', {PdfFile: 'https://example.com/library/documents/'+item.doc_file, headTitle: item.doc_title})}><Text style={styles.outlineBtnBox}>View</Text></TouchableOpacity>
              }

              {this.checkFileExists(item.doc_file) &&
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.DownloadDocument(item.doc_file)}>
                <Text style={styles.orangeBtn}>Download</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              }

              {item.dl_permitted===0 &&
                <Text style={{marginTop:10,color:'#f36a48', fontWeight:'bold'}}>This document is available for purchase from the website.</Text>
              }
            </View>
          </View>
          )
          } 
        }}             
        initialNumToRender={15}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
        windowSize={15}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader()}
        onEndReached={() =>this.LoadedDocs()}
        onEndReachedThreshold={0.8}
        ListFooterComponent={this.LoadingDocs()}
        bounces={false}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in docs [expo-file-system](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/#filesystemgetinfoasyncfileuri-options), FileSystem.getInfoAsync(fileUri, options) returns a promise, so you can modify like :

```
checkFileExists = async(doc) => { 
let result = await FileSystem.getInfoAsync(FileSystem.documentDirectory + 'app_docs/' + doc);
if(result.exists){
return true;
} else {
return false;
}

}
 {this.checkFileExists(item.doc_file) &&
              <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.DownloadDocument(item.doc_file)}>
                <Text style={styles.orangeBtn}>Download</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              }
```

Hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: I've just tried this. When i `console.log(result)` everything comes out as exists:false even although some of them should be true. They definitely exisit in the app_docs folder as i'm looping through them on a different screen.